# ReactJS: submit the form and call the function based on the radio button selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app there are two functions, form with radio buttons and a submit button.

```
//function that adds the selected image format to the state

handleImageFormatExportSelection(e) {
    this.setState({ ImageFormatExportSelection: [e.target.value] }, () => console.log('export image as:', this.state.ImageFormatExportSelection));
}

//function that exports image in JPG format
exportJPG(e) {...}

//function that exports image in PNG format
exportPNG(e) {...}

render() {
  return (

    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <div className="exportAs">
        <CheckboxOrRadioGroup
          title={'Export image as:'}
          setName={'exports'}
          controlFunc={this.handleImageFormatExportSelection}
          type={'radio'}
          options={this.state.exportOptions}
          selectedOptions={this.state.ImageFormatExportSelection} />
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => this.exportImage()}>Submit</button>
    </form> 
  );
}
```

**What should be the right way to call either exportJPG or exportPNG (based on the selected option in radio group) when user clicks the button?**

Thank you in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside of `exportImage`, just take the value of `ImageFormatExportSelection`, branch based on that.

```
if (this.state.ImageFormatExportSelection === "png") { // or whatever it is
  this.exportPNG()
} else {
  this.exportJPG()
}
```

**of note**, you have an `onClick` handler on the button and an `onSubmit` handler on your form - you probably want these two things to be or do the same thing. If you're using a form wrapper, there's probably a `submit` prop that helps with this - otherwise, use `type="submit"` on the button and drop the `onClick`